# Error con un ProgressDialog Xamarin Android "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

Tags: xamarin.android, progressdialog

Tengo un método, donde hago un rest para traer un json, y luego lo deserializo y lo pongo dentro de un DataGrid, hasta ahí todo bien, ahora lo que pretendo hacer es mientras se llena el data grid, poner un progress dialog, pero al hacerlo me marca éste error:

"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

El error me lo marca en el catch del método Rest, pero sólo me lo marca cuando el método de RelacionClientesRest() lo pongo dentro del

```
 var progressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Espere un momento", "Cargando registros", true);
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                RelacionClientesREST();

                RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this, "Toast within progress dialog.", ToastLength.Long).Show());

                RunOnUiThread(() => progressDialog.Hide());
            })).Start();
```

¿A que se debe? éste es mi código:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.RelacionClientes);
            ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            var progressDialog = ProgressDialog.Show(this, "Espere un momento", "Cargando registros", true);
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                RelacionClientesREST();

                RunOnUiThread(() => Toast.MakeText(this, "Toast within progress dialog.", ToastLength.Long).Show());

                RunOnUiThread(() => progressDialog.Hide());
            })).Start();
        }
```

Aquí mi método Rest

```
 public void RelacionClientesREST()
        {
            try
            {
                RestClient client = new RestClient("http://portalclientewa.azurewebsites.net/api/RelacionClientes/");
                var request = new RestRequest("GetData", Method.GET);
                request.Timeout = 1500000;
                request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
                request.AddParameter("idP", Idp);
                var temp = client.Execute(request).Content;
                var parsedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(temp).ToString();
                var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClientesProp>>(parsedJson).ToList();
                dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "No hay datos registrados", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas asignado el `ItemSource` de `dataGrid` en el hilo que no es de la vista. Tienes que ejecutar la asignacion en el hilo de la vista.
Cambia:

```
var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClientesProp>>(parsedJson).ToList();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;
//...
```

Por:

```
var lst = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClientesProp>>(parsedJson).ToList();
RunOnUIThread(()=>{
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = lst;
});  
//..
```

Comment: Correcto, muchas gracias @Einer